# MySQL-Need to select a row from one table to another table WHERE a <# will generate in SELECT statement

Tags: mysql

My first table has department name and number of phd's. My second table has the professor's name in particular departments. I need to pull the professors that are in the departments with less than 50 phd's.

```
  CREATE TABLE Dept (
        dname VARCHAR(100), 
        numphds INT
     );

    INSERT INTO Dept VALUES ( '"Chemical Engineering"', 32 );
    INSERT INTO Dept VALUES ( '"Civil Engineering"', 88 );
    INSERT INTO Dept VALUES ( '"Computer Sciences"', 47 );

    CREATE TABLE Prof (
        pname VARCHAR(100), 
        dname VARCHAR(100) 
    );

    INSERT INTO Prof VALUES ( '"Brian, C."', '"Chemical Engineering"' );
    INSERT INTO Prof VALUES ( '"Brown, S."', '"Civil Engineering"' );
    INSERT INTO Prof VALUES ( '"Jones, J."', '"Computer Sciences"' );


SELECT dname, numphds FROM dept WHERE numphds <50;
```

/*using the following SELECT statement is where I am lost and cannot seem to understand how to get the professor name within my results of the dname and numphds that are <50. I know I won't get the results by using the FROM DEPT statement. Any ideas*/

Comment: What are you currently getting? any errors? Try to maintain the same case in table and column names so `Dept` instead of `dept` in your query.

Comment: This is a basic `join` query.  Are you learning SQL?  If so you should specify this in your question.  If not, you should learn some SQL so you can use databases effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would give `Dept` a primary key and index column `deptId` and have this also on the `Prof` table. That way, there's no need to join on a text field.

```
CREATE TABLE Dept (
    deptId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    dname VARCHAR(100), 
    numphds INT
 );

INSERT INTO Dept VALUES ( 1, 'Chemical Engineering', 32 );
INSERT INTO Dept VALUES ( 2, 'Civil Engineering', 88 );
INSERT INTO Dept VALUES ( 3, 'Computer Sciences', 47 );

CREATE TABLE Prof (
    pname VARCHAR(100), 
    dname VARCHAR(100),
    deptId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY 
);

INSERT INTO Prof VALUES ( 'Brian, C.', 'Chemical Engineering', 1);
INSERT INTO Prof VALUES ( 'Brown, S.', 'Civil Engineering', 2);
INSERT INTO Prof VALUES ( 'Jones, J.', 'Computer Sciences', 3);
```

Second, you do realise that your text field have apostrophes?

To select them, using this format, I would `join` using the query

```
SELECT dept.dname, dept.numphds, prof.pname FROM dept join `prof` on prof.deptId = dept.deptId  WHERE dept.numphds <50;
```

Here is your [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b17d1/1).

Comment: Thank you! I am new to this and am trying to understand the basics. I have been learning through LYNDA.com and was recently told to use this site to help me clear some questions. I like the SQLFIDDLE, thank you for introducing me. I was using the apostrophes to have a different look in my results. I thought I had to use foreign key in order to get the answer, but I see you didn't use that. I will have to look more into this JOIN statement.

Comment: Hi @Mel_G, using a foreign key would be a good idea for data consistency and normalisation, but little steps to a bigger goal :)